# List Maintenance

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Hello I'm making a List Maintenance program which will maintain a list of float values. I keep getting stuck.
Can anyone help me.
Option 1 is the only option that is currently working.

```
Option 3
Enter your choice: 3

Delete Value from List (by location in list): 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python33/test 3.py", line 49, in <module>
main()
File "C:/Python33/test 3.py", line 14, in main
opt3()
File "C:/Python33/test 3.py", line 36, in opt3
list1.pop(delLocation)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

option 2

Enter your choice: 2

Delete Value from List (by value): 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python33/test 3.py", line 49, in <module>
main()
File "C:/Python33/test 3.py", line 12, in main
opt2()
File "C:/Python33/test 3.py", line 33, in opt2
list1.remove(delValue)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

and the exit does not work

i have to keep the code looking like this.

```
    list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def main():


    opt = -99
    while opt != 0:
      displayMenu()
      opt = intImput("\n\nEnter your choice: ")
      if opt == 1:
        opt1()
      elif opt == 2:
        opt2()
      elif opt == 3:
        opt3()
      elif opt == 4:
        opt4()
      elif opt == 0:
        print("Exiting...")
      else:
        print("Enter a valid option")

def intImput(prompt):
    try:
      return int(input(prompt))
    except:
      print("That input is incorrect")

def opt1():
    addValue=input("\nType in a value to add: ")
    list1.append(addValue)
def opt2():
    delValue=input("\nDelete Value from List (by value): ")
    list1.remove(delValue)
def opt3():
    delLocation=input("\nDelete Value from List (by location in list): ")
    list1.pop(delLocation)
def opt4():
    print(list1)
def opt0():
    print("\nExit")

def displayMenu():
    print("1.) Add Value to List\n")
    print("2.) Delete Value from List (by value)\n")
    print("3.) Delete Value from List (by location in list)\n")
    print("4.) Display List\n")
    print("\n\n0.) Exit")

main()
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework..

Comment: Please format/indent your code properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list1` is defined inside the `main()` function, so it will not be available in other functions. You can either

1. make `list1` a global variable (Read about global [here](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global)) or
2. pass `list1` as a parameter to all those functions.

Answer (score 1):

In main function do this:

```
global list1
list1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```